# Asynchronous JavaScript polling freezes the browser using setTimeout or setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, polling

I write a polling script to receive newly created data records. I want to execute the call in every `N` seconds.

I tried `setTimeout()` and `setInterval()` to run the polling **asynchronously**, but both freeze the browser while executing the `Polling()` function, which is really strange for me.

I call the `StarPolling()` function when the page is loaded. `APICall()` function is a `jQuery $.POST` function which is working well - and async - in any other situations.

This is the code I use with `setTimeout()`

```
var pollinginterval = 5000;
function StartPolling()
{
    setTimeout(Polling, pollinginterval);
}

function Polling()
{
    [... some code ...]

    var api_call = 'API_URL';
    var api_call_parameters = {
        [...]
    };
    APICall(api_call, api_call_parameters, function(json_response)
    {
        /* this is the callback belongs to the $.POST request */

        [... some code ...]

        setTimeout(Polling, pollinginterval);
    });
}
```

The version I tried using `setInterval()` is very similar except the recursive call.

I can not use Workers or HTML5 sockets for this because cross-browser support is a must.

Is there any way to run the polling in a **REAL asynchronous way**, or using a **new 'thread'** with JavaScript without freezing the browser?

**UPDATE:**
This is how the `APICall()` operates:

```
function APICall(call, parameters, success_callback)
{
    $.post(apibase + "" + call,parameters)
    .done(function(response){
        try
        {
            var json_response = $.parseJSON(response);
        }
        catch(error)
        {
            [...]
        }

        if(json_response.header.status == "OK")
        {
            success_callback(json_response);
        }
        else if(json_response.header.status == "error")
        {
            [...]
        }
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
        [...]
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**: I am testing the polling with a normal and private browser (firefox) window at the same time to try the functionality. I just noticed, that the problem only occurs when both windows are running the polling simultaneously.

Maybe it is a firefox bug...

Comment: What exactly does `APICall` do?  That's where the problem is. Is it doing synchronous AJAX?

Comment: @Pointy It could, but unlikely since it has a callback? Maybe it supports both?

Comment: I updated my question with the APICall function

Comment: Have you profiled your application?

Comment: If I were were you; first I shall do is to remove ajax call in APICall method and just put a console.log and see if browser is still hanging from repeated interval call.....

Comment: maybe you can use a `web worker` doing the xhr request (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663353/is-it-feasible-to-do-an-ajax-request-from-a-web-worker)

Comment: Maybe it's something in the [ ... some code ...] part before calling APIcall()

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that would freeze the browser.

Comment: Unless the returns JSON is huge or the code that processes the returned JSON takes a long time to run or something is overriding Ajax calls to make them synchronous, I don't see how this code freezes the browser.  Can you demonstrate the issue in a jsFiddle so we can do our own debugging on it.

Comment: @PatarticsMilán Just to clarify: `Polling` is supposed to run synchronously, while the AJAX request is supposed to happen asynchronously. Right?

Comment: FYI, you can run the Ajax code in a webWorker and process the result there and then just message the result back to the main thread where it can be inserted into the DOM.  If the processing is truly taking a long time, this would move all that work out of the main thread and into its own thread.

Comment: @Paul The first 'some code' generates the parameters for the call, and the second one updates some elements

Comment: @JosiahDaniels Polling() should run async.

Comment: @PatarticsMilán This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626680/is-settimeout-a-good-solution-to-do-async-functions-with-javascript

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: The problem is likely here: `[... some code ...]`

Comment: Have you tried removing the APIcall and leaving it's setInterval to see if it is the APICall causing the problem or the other codes? If it works, then maybe take out [ .. some code .. ] in the call back and see what happens

Comment: Just added a second update, it seems like the problem is because of the browser. Any way thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

The OP is wanting to run `Polling` in such a way that it doesn't interfere with the main thread (i.e. in a background thread). The only way to do this is to use a WebWorker, which he specifically doesn't want to use.

For a bunch of interesting reading see the W3 document about [event loops](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/webappapis.html#event-loops), but basically everything that happens in the browser is single threaded. All javascript will happen on the main thread (except for web workers). All `setTimeout` and `setInterval` do is queue a callback that will get run in the main thread after ~x seconds.

So sorry, there isn't any other way beside web workers.

Answer (score -1):

You may use a long polling pattern like this :

```
(function Polling() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(response) {
            //your try/catch here
        }, dataType: "json", complete: Polling });
    }, 5000);
})();
```

So the poll will attempt to finish before to restart, even if the server job is quite long...

Comment: Right, but what's wrong with his current pattern? why would it be freezing the browser?

Comment: Maybe in the server side... it will make a request every 5 seconds even if the server job is not finished.

Comment: but that would just stop the requests, it wouldn't freeze the browser.

Comment: This is already similar to the OP's current pattern so this does not answer the question.  The only difference I see is that the OP stops on errors and your code keeps going on errors.  So how does this answer the question?

Comment: @Karbos Right, which wouldn't have any effect on the "freezes my browser" problem.

Comment: I think  the "freezes my browser" problem comes from too much request, but maybe I'm wrong... See the @Akki619 suggestion first...