# Post json to server in regular intervals in plan javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, websocket

I am building a javascript plugin that a client will include in his. The plugin will track data user activity like page scroll, button clicks  mouse movements etc and then save to web storage. This data then need to be send to a back end server at regular intervals of say 5-10 seconds in json format.

- If I use a simple ajax for sending data by using setInterval method
  will that impact user browsing experience.?
- Will using websockets make more sense in this case or is there any other way?

**NOTE**: The backend server application is based on Spring MVC and the javascript plugin will push data to server externallly from clients application.

Comment: you can send multiple request in span of 10 , 15 seconds keeps async : true.

Comment: But that will block the browser if there are other ajax requests on clients website and can hamper user experience

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted minimal impact on the UI thread, you could spawn a `WebWorker` and do the `AJAX` requests from there.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663353/is-it-feasible-to-do-an-ajax-request-from-a-web-worker) is a good answer explaining `AJAX` requests in the context of a `WebWorker`.
[Here](http://techslides.com/html5-web-workers-for-ajax-requests) is another short example of implementing `AJAX` in a `WebWorker`.