# Muliple Ajax request in jquery freezes browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a requirement where i need to fetch around 50-100 urls using Ajax request and a loop.
This is working but, Firefox goes unresponsive and freezes.
Is there a way i can implement "go to next url when 1st one completed". Like when - then in jquery or something like that.

```
data = [url1, url2, url3, url4, url5, url6, ............]
for(i=0; i < 50; i++){
  $.ajax({
     async: false,
     type: 'GET',
     url: data[i],
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function(data){   
        alert(data);
     }
  });
}
```

I will also like to see if we can push, at least 2 URLs together to speed up.

**Update** :

Reviewed all the solution given below, but nothing worked. Now i am more exicted and looking for a solution which can run 'n' number of AJAX calls without any crash or un- responsiveness

Comment: Can't you send your whole `data` (containing the URLs) in a single `POST` request and get the result for each URL in the form of json objects? This will require only one Ajax call.

Comment: No, there are some query string associated and i need to do this separately using GET.

Comment: stop using `async:false`

Comment: @charlietfl That way it definitely freezes.

Answer (score 0):

If you must do this, you can chain your AJAX calls using jQuery deferred's then: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/. Also make things easier with a helper fn:

```
var urls = [url1, url2, ....];
function callAjax(url) {
  return function() {
    return $.ajax({url: ...});
  }
};

for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i+=2) {
  var dfd = callAjax(urls[i])();

  if(urls[i+1]) {
    dfd.then(callAjax(urls[i+1]));
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. That's the code. Just adapt it to what you already have.

Comment: Would is be possible to fiddle this with some example URls

Comment: Just populate the "urls" array with your URIs, and fill in the same $.ajax options you're using above.

Comment: Where will be the ajax request module go, after the url array ?

Comment: Hey Joeltine, thanks for you time..I was bit confused with the code. May you please put a fiddle example ?

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/fmfjko5z/. Note "/echo/html" is a special URL for jsfiddle demos to mock an AJAX call. Also, I basically wrote 99.9% of the code for you. You gotta learn to read a little more and experiment. Documentation is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

You must use web workers for performing an expensive task without interrupting the user interface.

If you want knowledge about workers, visit this : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/workers/basics/

If you just want to use them without understanding, you might use this : http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webworkers.asp

Comment: Can't we use WHEN-THEN. I heard that way we can know wheather first request completed and then go to next one ?

Comment: I'm not sure. You can try and then tell me ;-)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting we worker, Do you have any live example of Ajax request using web worker, I can follow with.

Comment: Webworker is not recommended for ajax call. See thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768452/web-workers-handling-ajax-calls-optimisation-overkill

Answer (score 0):

You can manage the loop in such a way that it calls ajax request after getting the response for 2 previously sent requests.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dataUrl = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7'];

    var completedRequest = 0;
    function getResults(start) {
        for(i=start; i < start+2; i++) {
            if(typeof (dataUrl[i]) != 'undefined') {
                $.ajax({
                    url: dataUrl[i],
                    complete: function(data) {
                        completedRequest ++;
                        if(completedRequest == 2 && (start+2) < dataUrl.length) {
                            getResults(start+2);
                            completedRequest = 0;
                        }   
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        completedRequest = 0;
     }
    //Initiate first request
    getResults(0);
});
```

Revised code. and here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/srupali/3ed0vg8p/1/)

Check the requests in console for better understanding.

Comment: Hi Rupali, Would you mind to put a example code in fiddle with some example urls

Answer (score 0):

Or you can call the ajax function like this:

```
urlsArray = ['/echo/html/', '/echo/html/', '/echo/html/'];

arrayIndex = 0;
doAjax(arrayIndex);      

function doAjax(arrayIndex) {
    var urlCount = arrayIndex + 1;
    var theURL = urlsArray[arrayIndex];
    alert(urlCount + ", Start AJAXing the url: " + theURL);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: theURL,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(urlCount + ", Done AJAXing the url: " + theURL);
            if (arrayIndex < urlsArray.length - 1) {
                arrayIndex += 1;
                doAjax(arrayIndex);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

Updated the answer and here is a JSFiddle demo:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k7q8wae9/)

Comment: Can you put your example in fiddle ?

Comment: Okay, I found the misspelling. But this code didn't work freezing browser again with 50 request.

Comment: @user3471169 I have updated the answer with jsfiddle example.